# How to update VBA code written for 32 bit to work with both 32 and 64?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update an `excel macro` written in `32 bit MS office` to work with `64 bit excel`. 
I keep getting the compile error in the hidden module when, I open the file in `64 bit`.

This error started after the office was updated to `64 bit`. The code works fine on `32 bit`. 
There are no `Pdfmaker.dot`, `Pdfmaker.xla` files in the excel startup folder nor do we use Norton.

I am a newbie at this, can anyone help me change the code to work with both `32 bit` and `64 bit`.

This is the code in module 1 which I think needs to be updated:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only `Sleep` then use this

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Further information [here](https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp)

**Update**:

> **Conditional compiling**
>
> If your code needs to run on both 32 bit and 64 bit Excel, then
>   another thing to do is add conditional compilation to your VBA.
>
> Microsoft devised two compile constants to handle this:
>
> VBA7: True if you're using Office 2010, False for older versions
>
> WIN64: True if your Office installation is 64 bit, false for 32 bit.
>
> Since the 64 bit declarations also work on 32 bit Office 2010, all you
>   have to test for is VBA7:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```

This is only needed in case your code needs to run on an Excel version before 2010.

Comment: `PtrSafe` is assuming VBA7, which isn't guaranteed in a 32-bit host. OP's `.dot` and `.xla` file extensions suggest Office 97-2003 file formats, which would be hosting VBA6.

Comment: Right, but I just "strongly" guessed the OP used Excel 2010 at the minimum ;-) And I also assumed he needs the code only in the new environment.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!!

Comment: @Shamuk note that if your Office 97-2003 files are opened in Office 2003, it won't. I would warmly recommend saving your files in .dotm and .xlam macro-enabled OpenXML file formats (otherwise such files are opened in "compatibility mode"). If a VBA6 host needs to be able to run that code, you'll need conditional compilation (see linked duplicate).

Comment: We are using office 2016 currently, but this macro was written in a much older version and so far it had been working fine till we updated to 64 bit. Including the PtrSafe in the declare statement did fix the compile error for me and successfully rant the macro. Hopefully it will work for the other users too. Thank you all for your help!